# Convert date and time string to DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, converters

I have string that displays date and time in the following format:

Thu Jan 03 15:04:29 2013

How would I convert this to a DateTime?  I have tried:

```
string strDateStarted = "Thu Jan 03 15:04:29 2013"
DateTime datDateStarted = Convert.ToDateTime(strDateStarted);
```

But this does not work.  In my program this value is read in from a log file so I am not able to change the format of the text string.

Comment: Something like `DateTime.ParseExact(str, "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy", null)`

Comment: [C# Convert date to datetime](https://www.google.se/search?q=C%23+convert+date+to+datetime)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use following code :

```
string strDateStarted = "Thu Jan 03 15:04:29 2013";           
DateTime datDateStarted;
DateTime.TryParseExact(strDateStarted, new string[] { "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy" }, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out datDateStarted);
Console.WriteLine(datDateStarted);
```

and sure if time is in 24 HRS format , then use HH. [More details](http://projects.gnome.org/gnumeric/doc/number-formatting-overview.shtml)

Answer (score 9):

Use one of the `*Parse*` methods defined on `DateTime`.

Either `TryParseExact` or `ParseExact` which will take a format string corresponding to the date string.

I suggest reading up on [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

In this case, the corresponding format string would be:

```
"ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy"
```

To be used:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("Thu Jan 03 15:04:29 2013", 
                    "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy", 
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: `hh` is a 12-hour format

Answer (score 3):

Try using [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx).

in your case the [format specified](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) should be:

```
Thu Jan 03 15:04:29 2013
```

and the call should look like:

```
DateTime logDate = DateTime.ParseExact(logValue, "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy",
                                     CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
```

The third parameter is set to the US culture, so that the `ddd` and `MMM` parts, correspond to `Thu` and `Jan` respectively.

---

In this case I'm recommending `ParseExact` instead of `TryParseExact`, because of the source of the data. If you are parsing user input, always use `TryParseExact`, because you cannot trust that the user followed the requested format. However, in this case, the source is a file with a well defined format, so any invalid data should be treated as exception, because they are, well, exceptional.

Also note that `*ParseExact` methods are very unforgiving. If the data does not exactly conform to the format specified, it's treated as an error.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  Yours didn't quite work, but Arshad's suggestion of: `DateTime.TryParseExact(strDateStarted, new string[] { "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy" }, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out datDateStarted);` worked.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [DateTime.TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
string yourDateTimeRepresentation = "R"; //for example
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(strDateStarted , yourDateTimeRepresentation , System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```